# PHP - Creating a trait with variables that cannot be accessed by the using class

Tags: php, traits

### The Problem

I have the following PHP code:

```
trait Trait1 {
    private $secret; // I want this to be only accessible in Trait1 and not in Foo

    public function getSecret() {
        return $this->secret;
    }

    public function setSecret($secret) {
        $this->secret = $secret;
    }
}


class Foo {
    use Trait1;

    public function foo() {
        return $this->secret; // This returns the $secret in Trait1
    }

}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setSecret("My secret!");
echo $foo->foo();
```

The above code outputs `"My secret"`

### What I Wanted?

I want the function `foo()` to not be able to run `$this->secret` (in other words to return a run time error). However unfortunately, it uses the private variable in `Trait1`.

### Why is this a problem?

The reason I don't like this behaviour is that if I accidently have an overlapping private variable that share the same variable name; it can cause problems if you didn't know you overridden a private variable.

For example:

```
trait Trait1 {
    private $secret;

    public function getTraitSecret() {
        return $this->secret;
    }

    public function setTraitSecret($secret) {
        $this->secret = $secret;
    }
}

class Foo {
    use Trait1;
    private $secret; // same variable name as in Trait1

    public function setFooSecret($secret) {
        $this->secret = $secret;
    }

    public function getFooSecret() {
        return $this->secret;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setTraitSecret("Trait secret!");
echo $foo->getTraitSecret(); // returns "Trait secret" as expected and wanted
echo $foo->getFooSecret(); // unfortunately also returns "Trait secret"

$foo->setFooSecret("Inner secret!");
echo $foo->getTraitSecret(); // unfortunately returns inner secret
echo $foo->getFooSecret(); // returns "Inner secret" as expected and wanted
```

The above code outputs similar to:

```
Trait secret!
Trait secret!
Inner secret!
Inner secret!
```

### A Solution?

Is there a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Use a name that is less likely to clash: `private $__trait1_secret`. Let pragmatism prevail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

> If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property with the same name, otherwise an error is issued. It is an E_STRICT if the class definition is compatible (same visibility and initial value) or fatal error otherwise.

So it's not a right way to do that.

Comment: A warning does not come up if you don't initialise $secret with a different value. But yes this is useful, but I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: Actually it will output a message: `PHP Strict standards...` if you enable `error_reporting`

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution to this problem is to set a value for `$secret` in the trait so that it cannot be used in the class `Foo`.

e.g.

```
trait Trait1 {
    private $secret = null;

    public function getTraitSecret() {
        return $this->secret;
    }

    public function setTraitSecret($secret) {
        $this->secret = $secret;
    }
}
```

Now the following will return a error:

```
class Foo {
    use Trait1;
    private $secret; // ERROR

    ...
}
```

This way, it is not possible to accidentally 'share' the same variable as it generates a fatal error.

Using the same value for both variables can result in just a warning.